# WordPress include contents of ajax in submitted message

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm a beginner with WordPress, the interface is really simple and user friendly. However I don't know how to approach in inserting some code.
For example, I have a contact page where the visitor inputs his vehicle registration plate number, but I would like to automatically validate the plate number with a JSON request to a REST api, and the returned data to be added to the message. If it were a simple PHP page I would have managed it easily. Should I put my gloves on and get dirty with the WordPress files ? Or is it easier than I imagine ?
Thank you

Comment: You need to create a template file for your contact form. Use jquery to submit the form via ajax to another php file. On that php file, return json as a reply (alerts, errors, success, etc). Process those alerts with jquery.

Comment: @peixotorms Thank you for your comment, gave me an idea to check the template's files and found the contact_form.php file which is handling the posted data, from here everything is easy. I thought it would be harder and break the Wordpress functionality etc.